# Is there a reverse concatenation operator for Javascript strings?

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

In Javascript,

```
hello += ' world'
// is shorthand for
hello = hello + ' world'
```

Is there a shorthand operator for the opposite direction?

```
hello = ' world' + hello
```

I tried `hello =+ ' world'` but it did not work: it just typecast `' world'` into `NaN` and then assigned it to `hello`.

Comment: No, there's no shorthand for that.

Comment: `" world" += hello;`, works but you need to capture the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a shorthand operator for the opposite direction?

No, all [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) [compound assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment) operators take the target as the left-hand operand.

Just use the `hello = ' world' + hello;` statement that you had. If you're doing this repetively, consider using an array as a buffer to which you can prepend by the [`unshift` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

Answer (score 2):

There is not really a shorthand for what you are describing.

An alternative approach would be to use String's [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) function:

```
var hello = 'hello';
var reverse = 'world '.concat(hello);
```

Comment: In Java it's look like this: 

`String title = title.concat("-"+title);`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have 'reverse' operator for strings, but there is `Array.reverse()` function which can help you in such cases:

```
var hello = "hello";

hello = (hello + ",world, beautiful").split(",").reverse().join(' ');

console.log(hello);  // beautiful world hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Concat returns the array without modifying existing arrays so where as you have

a= a.concat(b) // to put b at the end of a

You could just as easily do a = b.concat(a)? // put b followed by a. IE b at the beginning of the list a